# rxjava2 branching logic based on number of emissions

Tags: java, rx-java2, project-reactor

I want to branch logic depending on number of emissions from upstream.

To be precise, I want:

1. Nothing to happen when upstream is **empty**
2. One branch to trigger when the upstream **emits just one value and then completes**
3. One branch to trigger when the upstream **emits more than one value and then completes.**

I was scratching my head over how to approach this and I came up with something that works but seems awfully verbose. I am wondering if there's simpler way of doing this.

This solution is based on [valve](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersvalve) operator from RxJava2Extensions project.

The outline of the solution is as follows:

1. Use `publish(foo)` to subscribe multiple times to the upstream
2. Use `merge` for the two branches of logic
3. For 'more than one emission logic' use initially closed `valve` and open it on second emission, break the valve if there were no or just one emission. By breaking the valve I mean terminate the controlling `Publisher`
4. For 'just one emission logic' use initially closed `valve`. Use `ambArray` to either break the valve on no emissions or second emission or open the valve when there was exactly one emission.

So this seems to work, though my concerns are:

1. It looks over engineered for what it's doing. Can this be coded up simpler and clener?
2. The whole valve breaking business will trigger exception that I am just swallowing, but there could be other exceptions not valve related that I probably should distinguish here and let them propagate down the stream.
   [EDIT]The valve breaking is important, so that the valve for the single emission logic doesn't accumulate emissions that are meant for the multiple emissions logic and doesn't hog memory that way[/EDIT]

Here's the code:

```
Flowable.just(1,2,3,4,5) // +1 emissions
    //Flowable.just(1) // 1 emission
    //Flowable.empty() // 0 emissions
            .publish( //publish so that you get connectableFlowable inside
                f ->
                    Flowable.merge( //merge for the logic split
                        f.compose(
                            valve(f.scan(0, (sum, i) -> sum + 1) //scan to emit progressive count
                                   .filter(i -> i > 1) //filter for when count > 1
                                   .take(1) //take just first such count
                                   .concatMap(__ -> Flowable.<Boolean>never().startWith(true))  //and open the valve
                                   .switchIfEmpty(Flowable.empty()), //break the valve if there was just 1 element
                                  false) //start with the valve closed
                        )
                         .onErrorResumeNext(Flowable.empty()) //swallow the broken valve exception???
                         .map(__ -> "more than one elements!"), //here goes logic for +1 emissions
                        f.compose(
                            valve(
                                Flowable.ambArray(
                                    f.scan(0, (sum, i) -> sum + 1) //do progressive counts
                                     .switchIfEmpty(Flowable.never()) //if there was no elements then never end this guy
                                     .filter(i -> i > 1) //filter > 1
                                     .take(1) //take just first one
                                     .concatMap(
                                         __ -> Flowable.<Boolean>empty()) //if there was > 1 element then emit empty and break the valve so we
                                                                          //don't accumulate byte arrays that are meant for multipart upload
                                    ,
                                    f.count() //count the stream
                                     .map(c -> c == 1) //open valve if the count was 1
                                     .toFlowable()
                                     .concatWith(Flowable.never()) //and keep the stream opened forever
                                ),
                                false
                            )
                        )
                         .onErrorResumeNext(Flowable.empty())
                         .map(i -> "just one element") //here goes logic for just one emission
                    )
            )
            .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("haya! " + i))
            .blockingSubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected I made it too complex. I came with this way cleaner and simpler solution to the problem:

```
 public static <U, D> FlowableTransformer<U, D> singleMultipleBranching(
    FlowableTransformer<U, D> singleBranchTransformer,
    FlowableTransformer<U, D> manyBranchTransformer
)
{
    return
        fl ->
            fl.replay( //replay so that you get connectableFlowable inside
                       f -> f.buffer(2)
                             .take(1)
                             .switchMap(
                                 buf -> {
                                     switch (buf.size()) {
                                     case 1:
                                         return f.compose(
                                             singleBranchTransformer);
                                     case 2:
                                         return f.compose(
                                             manyBranchTransformer);
                                     default:
                                         return Flowable.empty();
                                     }
                                 }
                             )
            );

}
```